# How to disable monitor until reboot? Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, display

I'm looking to disable my computers monitor and have it not turn back on no matter what until a reboot, I was thinking maybe a batch file or vbscript, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could search the script which you need in the TechNet Gallery

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/

Like this below:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Turn-off-screen-4d173e0a